# How to check if a List of Lists contains another List

Tags: c#, list

I want to create a list which will hold two int values lets say it `arrfirst` and another list that will hold lists of `arrfirst`, lets say it `arrsecond` then check if `arrsecond` contains a defined `arrfirst` . Now i created lists but when i try to use `.Contains` it doesn't work.

```
List<List<int>> Eklenenler = new List<List<int>>();

for (int i = 0; i < YourTable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            prjAd = YourTable.Rows[i].Field<string>("F1");
            if (prjAd != "Servis Adresi")
            {
                wesAd = YourTable.Rows[i].Field<string>("F2");
                RowPrj = tbProjeler.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("prjAd") == prjAd).FirstOrDefault();
                RowWes = tbServisler.AsEnumerable().Where(k => k.Field<string>("wesAd") == wesAd).FirstOrDefault();
                prjId = RowPrj.Field<int>("prjId");
                wesId = RowWes.Field<int>("wesId");
                List<int> temp = new List<int>();
                temp.Add(prjId);
                temp.Add(wesId);
                if (!Eklenenler.Contains(temp))
                {
                    sqlExProjeEkle = "INSERT INTO NLK_PRJ_Webservisler (prjId,wesId) Values (" + prjId + "," + wesId + ")";
                    dco.Execute(sqlExProjeEkle);
                    Eklenenler.Add(temp);

                }
                else
                {

                }
            }                                                  
        }
```

This is my code. When i debugging, i can see `temp` values are right and also at second loop, `temp` is in `Eklenenler` list but it always goes in `if` block. For example, first loop shows `temp[0]=36` and `temp[1]=42` goes in if block and at second loop again `temp[0]=36` and `temp[1]=42` also `Eklenenler[0][0]=36` and `Eklenenler[0][1]=42` so it contains temp but it still goes in. How can i solve this problem and why this returns false and can't find this `temp` in `Eklenenler`. Thank you.

Comment: `if(row.SequenceEquals(anotherRow))` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do it with linq in just one line with something like this

```
if (!Eklenenler.Any(c => c.SequenceEqual(temp)))
{
    sqlExProjeEkle = "INSERT INTO NLK_PRJ_Webservisler (prjId,wesId) Values (" + prjId + "," + wesId + ")";
    dco.Execute(sqlExProjeEkle);
    Eklenenler.Add(temp);

}
else
{

}
```

Don't forget to add

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer using a foreach loop.

```
foreach (List<int> list in Eklenenler)
{
    if (list.SequenceEqual(temp))
    {
        //Do work
    }
}
```